# How change Checkbox body styles depeding of its input state at Mantine?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mantine

I'm using Mantine and have to implement a specific styled container for Checkbox input.

This checkbox will change its body styles depending of the input state(checked or not checked). Therefore, to change checkbox' container body style, I need to know the checkbox' input pseudo class state.

Inside the `theme` file. I have something like this:

```js
Checkbox: {
      styles: theme => ({
        body: {
          background: "white",
        },
        "input:checked": {
          body: {
            background: "black",
          }
        },
      }),
    },
```

This `body` and `input` value comes from StylesAPI from Mantine:

[image]

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
Checkbox: {
  styles: theme => ({
    body: {
      background: "white",
    },
    input: {
      "&:checked": {
        background: "black",
      }
    },
  }),
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this implementation will change the input background and not the body. However, I found a way to change it:

Inside the root, we can have "&[data-checked]", and then set the background of the root based at checked state.